# Itunes connect upload failed xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode9

Hey guys I try to upload my app archive to the Itunes connect but I get the error : "the bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken ".

I tried to change the name many times with special characters. 
I also tried to change the app id in my apple developer account.
I tried all the options but I get the same error.

Thank you for your help.

[image: The error]

Comment: Share your app name (App Display Name, if you've set or Project Name)

Answer (score 4):

Error message, itself says, what's problem with your build and what should you correct.

Your application name (or Display Name) associated with your build (IPA file) is already used by any other app (may your own other app or some else's) on Apple App/iTune store.

> **Change App Bundle/Display name and submit your build again.**

Share your app name (App Bundle/Display Name, if you've set or Project Name) to get better help.

How to change App/Display Name:

[image]

How to change Bundle Name:

[image]