# Error uploading build to iTunes Connect from Xcode organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When i am uploading build on iTune connect form Xcode organizer it giving me error like "The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken"

I have changed bundle id and app names but it still giving the same error

above link contain screen shot of error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Share your app's bundle name and display name.

Comment: Here's the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752789/itunes-connect-upload-failed-xcode-9

Answer (score -2):

change your build number in Target- Genral -Build and Archive the IPA.

Comment: Please see the error. It has absolutely nothing to do with the build number. The issue concerns the BundleID and/or Display name